# Summing rows on a tabular form in apex 4.2 for validation

Tags: oracle-apex

How can I sum fields on each row in a tabular form in APEX 4.2 to get a total for that row before I submit the page in order to do page validation?

For example if the first row has `6` in field `a` and `6` in field `b` the total for the first row should be `12` and on the second row if field `b` is `5` and field `c` is `5` the total for the second row should be `10`.

So I want to get totals based on rows not column. Is that possible?

Comment: i suggest you make a function that adds column a and b,then on custom attribute of column b set onchange="function()"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. If you know javascript/jquery, you'll get along well with my solution. This is what you have to do:

get the name attribute(using inspect element of your browser) of the field you want to sum up. Names of fields in oracle apex usually goes like 'f01' or 'f02' and so on. Once you get the fields, create a javascript function or you can use this one if you like:

```
    function sumUpRows(columnforsum,itemstobeadded){
       var numofcols = arguments.length;
       var numofrows = $("[name=" + arguments[0] + "]").length;
       var summ = 0;
       for(x=0;x<numofrows;x++){
           for(i=1;i<numofcols;i++){
            summ = summ + Number($("[name=" + arguments[i] + "]").eq(x).val());
           }
           $("[name=" + columnforsum + "]").eq(x).val(summ);
       }
    }
```

Put function above in "function and global variable declaration" part of your page. Then create a "before page submit" dynamic action. Set its action to "execute javascript" then put this line of code:

```
  sumUpRows("nameoffieldwheresumwillbeassigned","nameofitem1","nameofitem2","nameofitem3");
```

Here's a sample :

```
   sumUpRows("f04","f01","f02","f03");
```

For your question in the comment section, the answer is yes. To get the sum of a row automatically as you fill up the boxes on that row, you can use this function:

```
function sumUpRowsAsYouGo(whatelement){
    var numofrows=$("[name=f01]").length;
    var summ = 0;
    for(i=0;i<numofrows;i++){
        if($(whatelement).attr("id") == $("[name=" + $(whatelement).attr("name") + "]").eq(i).attr("id")){
            for(a=1;a<(arguments.length-1);a++){
                summ += Number($("[name="+ arguments[a] + "]").eq(i).val());
            }
            $("[name="+ arguments[arguments.length-1] + "]").eq(i).val(summ);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

you can use this function like this(put these lines in the "Execute on Page load" and "after refresh" dynamic action of your tabular form region):

```
$("[name=f01]").change(function(){
            sumUpRowsAsYouGo(this,"f01","f02","f03","f04");         
}   
);

$("[name=f02]").change(function(){
            sumUpRowsAsYouGo(this,"f01","f02","f03","f04");         
}   
);

$("[name=f03]").change(function(){
            sumUpRowsAsYouGo(this,"f01","f02","f03","f04");         
}   
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the total after the user puts a number into the field and tabs out and the total field automatically updates as opposed to waiting to hit the submit button to get the total?

Comment: @DarrellLawrence, check my answer. I have updated it.

Comment: @DarrellLawrence, you're missing one more argument. Put the name of the column that will catch the sum as the last argument for the function call so if the name is "f11" then the callback function of your every column must contain: `sumUpRowsAsYouGo(this,"f04","f05","f06","f07","f08","f11");`

Comment: Vance...could I use this function to sum up columns dynamically?  if so, what would I have to change?